# How do I solve the ice tic-tac-toe puzzle?

Tags: undertale

I need help with the ice tic-tac-toe puzzle. If you may not know what I'm talking about, let me try to explain where it is; it's after telling Papyrus what you did with his spaghetti and solving the puzzle after. Once you solve that puzzle after, there comes another tic-tac-toe obstacle on ice. How do I beat it?

Comment: If you could add a picture or a bit more description, that might help.

Comment: It has nothing to do with tic-tac-toe. The objective is to stand on every square and then press the button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the red arrows in the following image:

[image]